# Subtition of cursor for combining tables with time periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to combine two tables into one but I have to take validation dates into consideriation. For instance having two tables:

```
Address
ID          AddressValue    ValidFrom               ValidTo
----------- --------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
1           Pink Street     2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-20 00:00:00.000
2           Yellow Street   2010-01-20 00:00:00.000 2010-02-28 00:00:00.000

Phone
ID          PhoneValue   ValidFrom               ValidTo
----------- ------------ ----------------------- -----------------------
1           123456789    2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-15 00:00:00.000
2           987654321    2010-01-16 00:00:00.000 2010-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

I need to do combine them into new one:

```
NewSystem
ID          NewPhone    NewAddress      ValidFrom               ValidTo                 Version
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -------
1           123456789   Pink Street     2010-01-01 00:00:00.000 2010-01-15 00:00:00.000 4
2           NULL        Pink Street     2010-01-15 00:00:00.000 2010-01-16 00:00:00.000 3
3           987654321   Pink Street     2010-01-16 00:00:00.000 2010-01-20 00:00:00.000 2
4           987654321   Yellow Street   2010-01-20 00:00:00.000 2010-01-31 00:00:00.000 1
5           NULL        Yellow Street   2010-01-31 00:00:00.000 2010-02-28 00:00:00.000 0
```

The idea is quite simple. I create periods based on dates and then query each table in subqueries. I pasted my solution here: http://pastebin.com/cdKePA9X.

Right now I am trying to get rid of the cursor but I failed. I tried to use CTE but without success. Maybe someone of you faced similar problem or know how to combine these tables into one without using cursor. I pasted the 'create table' scripts here: http://pastebin.com/BeRspb6K.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, construct new date ranges by merging the date ranges from the source tables.  Second, for each new date range, lookup the valid data in the source tables.

```
WITH
  old_ranges(d1,d2) AS (
     SELECT ValidFrom,ValidTo FROM @Address UNION
     SELECT ValidFrom,ValidTo FROM @Phone   
  ),
  new_ranges(d1,d2) AS (
    SELECT d,LEAD(d) OVER(ORDER BY d)
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT d
      FROM old_ranges 
      UNPIVOT(d FOR dx IN (d1,d2)) p
    ) t
  )
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d1) AS ID,
  NewPhone,
  NewAddress,
  d1 AS ValidFrom,
  d2 AS ValidTo
FROM new_ranges
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT PhoneValue AS NewPhone
  FROM @Phone
  WHERE ValidFrom <= d1 AND ValidTo >= d2
) x1
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT AddressValue AS NewAddress
  FROM @Address
  WHERE ValidFrom <= d1 AND ValidTo >= d2
) x2
WHERE d2 IS NOT NULL
```